# Importing CSV file into multiple models at one time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, csv

I have 3 models, Church, which has many Locations, which has many Pastors.

```
require 'csv'  
csvfile = File.read("testimport.csv")
csv = CSV.parse(csvfile, :headers => false)
csv.each do |row|
  c = Church.new
     c.name = row[0]
     c.url = row[10]
   c.locations.build(:address => row[3], :zipcode => row[5], :phone => row[6], :email => row[2], :city => row[4])
   c.save
end
```

As you can see in my short block of code I am creating a Church and its first location. How would I also add a pastor to that?

For instance will this work?

```
require 'csv'  
csvfile = File.read("testimport.csv")
csv = CSV.parse(csvfile, :headers => false)
csv.each do |row|
  c = Church.new
     c.name = row[0]
     c.url = row[10]
     location = c.locations.build(:address => row[3], :zipcode => row[5], :phone => row[6], :email => row[2], :city => row[4])
     location.pastors.build(:name => row[10])
     location.save
   c.save
end
```

Is there another way I should be going about this? Trying to move thousands of records from one rails app to another.

Comment: this should work, but you need to be sure using `accept_nested_attributes_for` macro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work, the following is what I used. Let me know if there is a smarter way to do this. NOTE: if you are trying to do this, place the csv file in the root of your rails directory and execute this script line by line in the console. At least thats how I got it working.

```
require 'csv'  
csvfile = File.read("testimport.csv")
csv = CSV.parse(csvfile, :headers => false)
csv.each do |row|
   c = Church.new
     c.name = row[0]
     c.url = row[10]
   c.locations.build(:title => "Sanctuary", :address => row[3], :zipcode => row[5],     :phone => row[6], :email => row[2], :city => row[4])
   c.save
loc = c.locations.first
loc.pastors.build(:firstname => row[1])
loc.save

end
```

Answer (score 1):

I take a slightly different approach to this, I have found a two step process is easier to use and build on.

The first step is load the data.

I use two 'staging' tables.
Something like:

```
staging_header
id           Integer  Unique  Primary Key
run_number   Integer  Unique
run_name     String

staging_data:
id                 Integer  Unique  Primary Key
staging_header_id  Integer
element1           String
element2           String
element3           String
uploaded?          Boolean  # Placed on the individual records allows restarts. 
...
```

So I load the testimport.csv directly into these loading tables - which support multiple runs if you make the run_number unique (sequence, etc.)

Now you have the data in sql and available in rails.

Now write the code to actually populate the application tables from this loading area.

This will also help you with the speed issue.  Rails will only be inserting a few records per second, so you want to be able to do restarts, pauses, etc.

This will also help with validation.  Initially you just want to load the data, regardless of any constraints (not null, unique, etc.).

Once loaded into staging you can be more selective and apply validations as you wish.

Comment: Ok so to clarify my understanding, your saying that you setup a couple models and populate them using a method similar to what i described? And you then populate your production models using those "staging" tables?

Comment: Yeah, your basic method still applies and this approach really helps to separate out the 'loading from csv' and 'populating tables' functions.  The load from csv can be very dumb and small.  The populate tables will be the one that gets changed going forward, with additional validations and business rules.

Comment: 1 example - imagine a batch of record where 1% are 'bad'.  With the load from csv, you can correct the source until all are good, then load that into tables.  Whereas if the records had been directly loaded into the final tables, you will have a more complex synchronization issue, either deleting records, or figuring out which ones to reject, etc.