# How do I create a Validation Error Log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activeadmin

I have a rails 3 application that involves a lot of importing of CSV files from a third party into various rails models. I have developed some scripts to perform most of the heavy lifting and today I added a lot of validation to the models to make sure valid data is going into the models/tables.

I'd also like to do some logging of validation errors so I can stay on top of all of the data processing and catch and correct validation errors quickly.   To that end, I have taken the following steps:

1. I created a ValidationError model to store validation errors.
2. I initially create an instance using new.
3. Once the object is built, I use valid? method and an if conditional to determine if the object it valid.  If the the object is valid, I simply save it. If the object isn't valid I create a validation error record.
4. I use the errors method to populate my ValidationsError instance.
5. Then I create the ValidationError.create(validation_hash[])
6. I'll display the validationError model in my ActiveAdmin dashboard and send out an email when validation entries are created.

Question(s): Is my proposed approach to capturing validation error reasonable.  Are there approaches that have been used by others that may be better/preferable to what I propose. Is anyone aware of any gems or built-in functionality that would accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [validation_rage](https://github.com/bumi/validation_rage) gem. you might be able to use that gem to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

have also a look at this :)

[Importing CSV file into multiple models at one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944931/importing-csv-file-into-multiple-models-at-one-time)

and rail_admin_import gem, maybe you can expand with above staging table approach.